# Suppression of current in the ground plane

Tags: circuit-analysis, pcb, current, rf, pcb-design

I’m designing an antenna with two polarisation. The stripline from the two polarisation are close in one layer therefore the isolation between the two pol is degraded because of some current flowing in the ground plane. What would you suggest to suppress those current?

Comment: remove the voltage difference across the ground plane

Comment: Separate the traces for the two polarizations.  Don't they enter the individual radiators at right angles to one another?

Comment: @jsotola I have tried to place some grounding vias connecting the two ground plane between the two striplines but this seems to make things worse

Comment: @SteveSh the traces don’t couple in the plane of the radiator, they couple in another plane

Answer (score 0):

Your title asks for suppression in the ground place. That makes no sense,  the field around the stripline induces current in the ground plane, otherwise it wouldn't be a stripline (but a free-hanging wire antenna).

I'm hence interpreting you like you think that relatively far away from one strip line, there's field caused by it that interacts with the other stripline. That might be, but that mostly means your ground isn't sufficient conductive (i.e. *more* current directly below/above the stripline is the solution), or you've really, really put the two striplines too close together.

Comment: I’m just saying that the stripline couple between each other because of those currents in the ground plane. The stripline are not very close but I cannot increase the distance between them so I have to find different solution. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: I think we need to see a picture of the radiator and stripline feeds.  We build dual-pol radiators all the time with a shared ground plane.  What amount of isolation are you getting, and what are the trying to achieve?